# React submenu with authorization

Tags: java, reactjs, json, spring, spring-security

I started a project in which the frontend is React, in which I have already written the menus, but I have only just written the authentication based on a tutorial. The authentication works perfectly, but I wrote the submenus completely differently than in the tutorial and I cannot implement my code in the tutorial's code. Can you help me how to use my submenu? The way I tried it didn't work because I get this error message: `"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, zip, state, city, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."`. I think it's because my API call give an JSON in that form:

```
{
    "name": "Vendor 1",
    "zip": "1001",
    "state": "NY",
    "city": "New York",
    "id": 1
},
```

All code is in comment.

Comment: My submenu: https://pastecode.dev/s/0HYvgKRv
Tutorial submenu: https://pastecode.dev/s/zNQoyUCM
The tutorial: https://github.com/bezkoder/react-jwt-auth/tree/master